# reset textbox password using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this textbox with the button and submitting the data using ajax

```
<input type="password" id="password" />
<button id="addaccount" onclick="showload();">Add</button>
```

the showload(); indicates the loading of the page, it shows the pure white background with 50% opacity on it and a loading .gif in the center.

now how can I reset the password textbox in the javascript?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addaccount").click(function(){
        var password = $("#password").val();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "auth_adduser.php",
                data: {
                    password:password
                    },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#successresult").html(data);
                }
            });

    });
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `$("#password").val("");`

Comment: use `$("#password").val("")`

Comment: document.getElemenetById('password').value="" 
 **Live Native**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After succesfull ajax execution `$("#password").val("");` reset password

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addaccount").click(function(){
        var password = $("#password").val();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "auth_adduser.php",
                data: {
                    password:password
                    },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#successresult").html(data);
                  $("#password").val("");
                }
            });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you can clear the input value by setting it to an empty string

```
$("#password").val("")
```

Answer (score 3):

Get element by id and reset the value.

```
$('#password').val('');
```

---

If you want to reset entire form then simply trigger reset event. This will only work if the elements are inside a form.

```
$('#password').closest('form').trigger('reset');
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing value of an input using jQuery

```
$("#password").val('');
```

Resetting = setting value to ' '

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the same click event,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addaccount").click(function(){
    var password = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "auth_adduser.php",
            data: {
                password:password
                },
            success: function(data){
                $("#successresult").html(data);
                $("#password").val(''); //reset password field.
            }
        });

   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Following in Success Function:
In Jaavascript: Use

```
document.getElementById("password").reset();
```

In Jquery :

```
$("#password")[0].reset();
```

See Full Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addaccount").click(function(){
        var password = $("#password").val();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "auth_adduser.php",
                data: {
                    password:password
                    },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#successresult").html(data);
                    $("#password")[0].reset();
                }
            });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. After you do all of your processing, enter:

```
$("#password").val("")
```

If you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Almost possible ways :D

```
$("#password").val("");
$("#password").attr("value", "");

$("#password")[0].value = "";
$("#password")[0].setAttribute("value", "");


document.getElementById("password").value = "";
document.getElementById("password").setAttribute("value","");
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
$('#password')
.val('')
.attr('value', '');
```

using javascript

```
document.getElementById("password").value = "";
document.getElementById("password").setAttribute("value","");
```